# Weird sum in excel when using SUMIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can't understand why my formula sums up to this big of a number? The sum changes when changing the the range of the criteria. The criteria is blank, so I thought and hoped the sum would be 0?

[image: Excel]

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What is the answer supposed to be and why? What are you looking for in `Column H`?

Comment: Why are you wrapping a SumProduct around a SumIf?? Looks like this is an XY Problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: In column H the plan is that I can write in Test1 and Test2, and the the sum would be 5. But since the range in SUMIF is the entire column H, this does not happend.

Comment: @teylyn If I dont the formula will sum one and one row. https://imgur.com/a/InEQFjm (Had to change the range so the spill could work)

Comment: I would add a column - enter 1 for those included and use sumproduct().

Comment: How would Test1 and Test create a value of 5? I could see how `Test2` and `Test3` might be what you mean?

Comment: Start over. What do you want to achieve? Don't start with a wonky formula that is all wrong from the get-go. What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the processing logic. I don't see how `Test1` with an associated value of `1` and `Test2` with an associated value of `2` would result in 5. Explain.

Comment: Maybe this is what you were looking at: https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-equal-to-one-of-many-things because it uses a sumif in a sumproduct.  it works fine if you leave out the "*" parts: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,H:H,B:B))`  But you should make the ranges smaller because it takes a long time to sum a million rows.  Maybe something like `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A1:A1000,H1:H10,B1:B1000))`

Comment: The reason for "*" is that in the actually doc I'm working in, I want to check if a word from list in column H is in the full description in column A. example check if cherrie is in AppleCherriePie. Cant show to doc since its my bankin transcript...

Answer (score 2):

The formulas are behaving correctly, what's *weird* is how you're using them. I can't think of a reason to use `Sumif` combined with `Sumproduct` (though somebody on here probably could).

To explain what's happening, you're creating a spill-range/array with your `sumif` formula because your middle parameter is a range (`H:H`), rather than a single value (such as `test1`). This is adding up *all* the values of the four cells with a value in column A (`1+2+3+4=10`). From there, it's spilling this into every row of excel, which is due to your middle parameter.

After that completes, the `sumproduct` function is summing all of these values, which is why you're seeing a value of 10,485,760 (the exact number of rows in Excel multiplied by 10).

If you're using sumproduct, you would want to use multiple array parameters. Your current formula only has one, which is no different than just using the sum value.